# Why is my main storyboard not picked up for localisation when I add a new language?

Tags: ios, localization, xcode9

I am starting to localise my app to other languages but when I add a new language in Xcode 9, only my launch screen storyboard is picked up for localisation not my main storyboard, I had expected both to be picked up for localisation, how do I get my main storyboard included for localisation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your storyboard -> In file inspector there is a button "Localize", i believe that is what you need.

Comment: That was it, for some reason my storyboard was not in the base folder, following this procedure moved it back to the base folder and thus it got added to the export when I export the CLIFF file for our translators

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend localizing your app using Storyboard.

Why: In future, you won't be able to send a storyboard to the interpreter to translate it. It's slower and heavier. It takes more time.

Instead, there is **another solution**. Use `NSLocalizedString` to do localization. Then you will generate the file with translations and have 1 file for 1 language of the app. It's a common practice among developers and I always have been doing it that way.

Check out this **tutorial** it seems to be good from what I've looked through: [link](https://www.ibabbleon.com/iphone_app_localization.html).

Comment: i thought Xcode would extract the strings from the Storyboard into the XLIFF files automatically, I understand I don't want to send the entire SB to translators

Comment: I see. haven't done that way before and haven't heard anyone doing that way. so can't say for sure that it's a not right solution. sorry

Comment: I am using nslocalizedstring for the alertviews etc that are code generated just to clarify

Comment: I am using NSLocAlizedString for all my code generated strings but not for any storyboard generated strings like button names etc that are connected to segues only

Comment: @MattDouhan got it. Thanks for clarifying. To be honest I prefer to set all the text from code in case I know that there is a localization that may happen one day. Also it’s much easier to rename stuff in case something changes since storyboard loads slow.